# How to save checkbox value into the grid depening on the checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I have a Grid where User selects values from dropdowns, enters some free text in a text box and checks on a checkbox button whether that task is acheived or not.

This is what I wrote in my code
`acf.isAchieved = chkAchieved.Enabled;`

I tried to change the value to check if Im hitting the right code or not.
  `acf.isAchieved = false;` and
  `acf.isAchieved = true;`
It just either changes all the check boxes to be checked or not checked or the code doesnt work.
please help me fix it

```
protected void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)this.Parent.FindControl("lblCenterNo");
            ActionPlanPresenter actionPlan = new ActionPlanPresenter();

            int count;
            if (editFalg)
            {

            }

            foreach (GridViewRow grd in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                TextBox txtdesc = (TextBox)grd.FindControl("txtDescription");
                TextBox txtComments = (TextBox)grd.FindControl("txtComments");
                DropDownList ddlCategory = (DropDownList)grd.FindControl("ddlCategory");
                DropDownList ddlSubcategory = (DropDownList)grd.FindControl("ddl_subcategory");
                CheckBox chkAchieved = (CheckBox)grd.FindControl("CheckBoxAchievedEdit");
                CheckBoxList chkBoxList = (CheckBoxList)grd.FindControl("cbList");
                if (GridView1.Rows.Count == grd.RowIndex + 1)
                {
                    if (editFalg)
                    {

                        Presenters.Presenters.ActionPlanPresenter _planPresenter = new Presenters.Presenters.ActionPlanPresenter();
                        Database.Action act = new Database.Action();
                        List<ActionChild> lstActc = new List<ActionChild>();
                        act.idCenter = actionPlan.getCenterIdByNumber(lbl.Text.Trim());
                        act.idCategory = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
                        act.ActionDescription = txtdesc.Text;
                        act.idSubCategory = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSubcategory.SelectedValue);
                        act.Comments = txtComments.Text;
                        act.Achieved = chkAchieved.Checked;
                        act.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        act.CreatedBy = DM.Utility.ExtensionMethods.EnumExtensionMethods.GlobalCommon.CurrrentUser;
                        act.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        act.ModifiedBy = DM.Utility.ExtensionMethods.EnumExtensionMethods.GlobalCommon.CurrrentUser;
                        act.isActive = true;
                        act.isDelete = false;
                        foreach (ListItem li in chkBoxList.Items)
                        {
                            if (li.Selected)
                            {
                                ActionChild actC = new ActionChild();
                                actC.idCalendar = Convert.ToInt32(li.Value);
                                // actC.Comments = txtComments.Text;
                                actC.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                                actC.CreatedBy = DM.Utility.ExtensionMethods.EnumExtensionMethods.GlobalCommon.CurrrentUser;
                                actC.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                                actC.ModifiedBy = DM.Utility.ExtensionMethods.EnumExtensionMethods.GlobalCommon.CurrrentUser;
                                actC.isActive = true;
                                actC.isDelete = false;
                                actC.Selected = true;
                                lstActc.Add(actC);
                            }
                        }
                        _planPresenter.InsertNewAction(act, lstActc);
                        editFalg = false;
                    }
                }                      

                    else
                    {
                        Label lblID = (Label)grd.FindControl("lbl_ActionId");

                        ActionSelfModel acf = new ActionSelfModel();
                        acf.categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
                        acf.subcategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSubcategory.SelectedValue);
                        acf.isAchieved = chkAchieved.Enabled;

                        acf.comments = txtComments.Text.Trim();
                        acf.Description = txtdesc.Text;

                        // acf.SubCategoryName = txtSubCatName.Text;
                        acf.idAction = Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text);
                        List<FIN_Calendar> lstCal = new List<FIN_Calendar>();
                        foreach (ListItem li in chkBoxList.Items)
                        {
                            FIN_Calendar c = new FIN_Calendar();
                            if (li.Selected == true)
                            {
                                c.idCalendar = Convert.ToInt32(li.Value);
                                c.Period = li.Text;
                                lstCal.Add(c);
                                //acf.Cals.Add(c);
                                //  acf.Cals.Add(c);

                            }
                        }
                        acf.Cals = lstCal;
                        _actionPlan.updateAction(acf);
                    }             

            }

        }
```

Comment: is it winforms? or wpf?

Comment: Enabled? Why not Checked?

Answer (score 0):

A datagridview is a representation of data. The datagridview will save nothing in itself.
Please read about [datagridviews and their data sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - and then if still in a troublesome condition, rephrase and come back here.

Comment: It is a grid view but its actually a control.

Comment: My grid works fine. i dont have any problem with that , except this thing